# How to create a JsonArrayContract?

Tags: json.net

I have an array that contains an object, I'll call it ComplexThing, that needs special instructions to deserialize.  I have created a ContractResolver to fix a reference loop problem I was having for a different object.  I thought I could override CreateMemberValueProvider() and create an IValueProvider that would let me define how to deserialize a ComplexThing.  The problem I'm finding is that because ComplexThing is always in an array, CreateMemberValueProvider() is never called for ComplexThing.

I'm guessing I need to override CreateArrayContract() to create a JsonArrayContract.  I'm having a hard time finding an example of how to create a JsonArrayContract or find a ArrayContractResolver that I can extend.  For the ContractResolver I'm currently using, I extended DefaultContractResolver.  Is there any such thing for arrays?

Edit:

I found a solution to this.  I'm not sure it's the correct one, but it seems to work.  I would still like some answers if someone has a better solution.

What I did was in CreateArrayContract() I check to see if it's an array of type ComplexThing.  If it is I added a custom converter to the ItemConverter.

```cs
protected override JsonArrayContract CreateArrayContract(Type objectType)
{
    var result = base.CreateArrayContract(objectType);
    if (typeof(ComplexThing).IsAssignableFrom(result.CollectionItemType))
    {
        result.ItemConverter = new ComplexThingConverter();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Converter:

```cs
public class DataSnapInConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(ComplexType).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object  existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var result = serializer.Deserialize(reader, typeof(ComplexType));            
        return result;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }
}
```